# ошибка компиляции gcc. dereferencing pointer to incomplete type

Tags: c, gcc, struct

gcc 4.9 ругается на определение функции my_struct. error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type

```
struct my_struct;
void* start(void *args);
...
void* start(void *args){
  struct my_struct *a = (struct my_struct *) args;
  while((a->b)==1){
  };
  return NULL;
};

struct my_struct{
    int b;
};
```

Но при этом

```
int main()
{
  struct my_struct a;
  a.b = 1;
}
```

В главной функции при этом проблем нет. Если перенести **определение** структуры до вызова определения функции то всё работает.

В чистом си необходимо определить все структуры до объявления функции?

Comment: функции тут конечно не причем. Но да, структуры должны быть определены перед кодом упоминающем их содержимое. компилятор просто не знает есть ли в структуре поле 'b'

Comment: Я бы сказал, что по сути forward declaration нужны для того, чтобы компилятор отличал один `void *` (или типы аргументов в прототипах) от другого и красиво ругался на невнимательность программиста.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Да, всё верно, и не только для `gcc`, а и вообще для любого компилятора для `C` либо `C++`.

Весь код распознаётся так или иначе сверху-вниз, слева-направо (конкретно `GCC` использует `Flex` в совокупности с `GNU Bison` либо `yacc`, при этом используется `LALR`-алгоритм). При ипользовании имени структуры до того, как она была объявлена, то компилятор не сможет её распознать т. к. ещё не встречал её объявления.

```
void f(struct my_struct *a) {} // ошибка компиляции - my_struct неизвестна
//.....
struct my_struct { int b; };  // непосредственно определение структуры
```

Если же объявить структуру, но определить её в коде позже, то компилятор не будет знать ничего о ней, и соответственно будет ограничен при парсинге выражений с её участием - не сможет выделить необходимую память, доступиться к какому-либо её элементу

```
struct my_struct; //мы указываем компилятору, что где-то ниже должна быть определена структура с именем my_struct.
void f(struct my_struct *a) { // всё отлино, мы знаем, что ниже должна быть структура с таким именем.
    a->b; } //ошибка компиляции - у компилятора нет сведений, что структура my_struct содержит поле b
struct my_struct { int b; };  // непосредственно определение структуры
```

Comment: спасибо большое за разъяснение. Упустил момент со структурами. Думал, что их можно объявлять и определять по аналогии с функциями.

Comment: @Bambaleila, можно, но ограниченно - объявить указатель на структуру и так же работать с этим указателем без его разименовывания (т. е. без доступа к элементам структуры).

Comment: Ну, алгоритм разбора синтаксиса в стандарте не специфицирован, так что ссылка на конкретный алгоритм, как мне кажется, не вполне корректна (и вроде бы LALR, в отличие от LL-разборов праворекурствен). Но вот то, что объявления работают в порядке появления в тексте, требуется стандартом вне зависимости от алгоритма синтаксического анализа.